# Is it possible to edit user's contact from app (Windows Phone 8 or 8.1)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, contacts

I would like to know if it's possible to edit a contact from user's contact list from an app in Windows Phone 8 or Windows Phone 8.1, or just open the page that does this on the device.

I know that it's possible to retrieve all the contacts or save a new one, but I didn't find anything about editing a contact.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cant edit a contact you dont own.

> However apps still cannot manipulate existing contacts that originate from somewhere else. In this sense, the data that belongs to an app is somewhat isolated from the rest. This concept is what is described as contact store – each app can have its own, writable part of the global contacts, but can only read from the rest.

[source](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Contacts-Integration.aspx) (Great article and a good read)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN had a page where it showed all the basic operation on the ContactStore but it was buried quite deep in the documentation.  Adding, Updating and deleting is permitted.

[How to perform basic custom contact store operations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207024(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Updatingacontact)

---

The link includes full working examples of each operation.

Comment: "Note:
The custom contact store APIs only provide access to the contacts created by your app. If your app needs read-access to the phone’s contact store or calendar, there are different APIs that you should use. For more information, see Read-only access to Contacts and Calendar for Windows Phone 8."

Guess this doesn't work for me. I needed to edit contacts that were created on the device.